# How to merge two rtf strings in C#

Tags: c#, rtf

I have two strings, that contains rtf.
First text

```
»R°T°F«ZMwMAAB+LCAAAAAAABAC1kk1v2zAM etc.
```

Second text

```
»R°T°F«ZcQMAAB+LCAAAAAAABAC1Uj2P2zAM/S etc.
```

how can I concat those strings without losing formatting of each string?

I tried to split text and rtf of each string. After that I concat text and merge rtf with

```
public static string MergeRTF(string rtf1, string rtf2)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richBox = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
                richBox.Rtf = rtf1;
                richBox.Select(richBox.Text.Length, 0);
                richBox.SelectedRtf = rtf2;
               return richBox.Rtf;
}
```

Then i combine text and merged rtf but it losts part of formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting my post. But i mean:
string 1 = "First text»R°T°F«ZMwMAAB+LCAAAAAAABAC1kk1v2zAM";
string 2 = "Second text»R°T°F«ZcQMAAB+LCAAAAAAABAC1Uj2P2zAM/S";

Comment: @PeterSmith Yes, i tried this. But when i opens resulting string in RichEdit it gives error message: wrong rtf format.

Comment: If someone interested, i found a solution. But for do this you need DevExpress RichEditDocumentServer. So, with it you can just set property RtfText equals to first string, then call Document.AppendRtfText.